# array extract with php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with extract value on array multidimensional, print_r array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [referent] => vespucci
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [referent] => colombo
            )

    )

[1] => eb38f736ef826180218c8c0c804f7bebe6d995c1
)
```

I'd like extract 'referent' values but if I get this error of nested foreach:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
```

exactly in line of second foreach:

```
foreach($posts as $post)
            {
                foreach($post as $po)
                {
                    $change[] = $po;
                }
            }
```

where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the name of the multidimensional array?

Comment: On the second iteration, `$post` is a string. You cannot `foreach` a string.

Comment: The warning is coming from that last element in the parent array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the second element of your array that is not an array;
You could do this by:

```
foreach($posts[0] as $post)
    $change[] = $post;
```

And if you only want the referent value you could use:

```
foreach($posts[0] as $post)
    $change[] = $post['referent'];
```

And here is general:

```
foreach($posts as $post){
   if( is_array($post)){
      foreach($post as $po){
          if(isset($po['referent']))
            $change[] = $po['referent'];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
The problem is that I have to take all the values ​​and referent are variable, once it could be two, once even ten.

Comment: You could iterate through all your elements array and check if is_array() and then if isset($theInnerarray['referent'];

Comment: I added the general code.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is not an array when it gets to `$post[1]`.

So it should work fine on the first one, but the second one fails because you can't `foreach` into something that isn't an array =).

Do you have to iterate over the array, or can you just directly get the value since you know where it is?